# Firebug - Keep window open after popup closes

Tags: firebug

By default when a new browser window closes , firebug does as well; however, I'm trying to step through some things to create a test plan and need to see the Net->Post activity.

Is there a way to keep this open.  I've tried having FireBug open in a new window; however, once the post activity takes place the javascript on my page tells the browser to close so I can't inspect the Post.

Any ideas?

Comment: closing a window destroys all the code/dom/whatever in it, meaning FB has nothing to attach to. Disable the window close bits until you're done debugging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to inspect the network activity in Firebug you'll need to stop the popup window from closing. If you are in control of the javascript in the popup, you can simply add the following (works in FF & Chrome, maybe others):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return false;
}
```

If you don't have access (e.g. in my situation where it's a third party widget) you can just fire up Firebug once the popup is loaded, and run the above code in the "console" tab.

This stops the window from closing, allowing you to inspect the contents of the Net tab etc.